# F# composition of types. How to instantiate and use.

Tags: .net, types, f#, type-conversion

I can create and instantiate simple types like this:

```
type MyStr1 = MyStr1 of string
let myStr1 = MyStr1("aaa")

type MyStr2 = MyStr2 of string
let myStr2 = MyStr2("bbb")
```

Then I can compose them into third type:

```
type MyStr3 = MyStr1 -> MyStr2
```

How to instantiate MyStr3? What will this object represent? What is it for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is `type alias` for function type:

```
type MyStr3 = MyStr1 -> MyStr2
```

This is not strictly a type, just an alias you know :)

But you could use it to create a value of this alias:

```
let myFun : MyStr3 =
    fun (MyStr1 str) -> MyStr2 str

let result = myFun myStr1
printfn "%A" result //prints `MyStr2 "aaa"`
```

**ADDED**:
Asnwering your comment:

```
type MyStr4 = MyStr4 of string

type MyStr3 = MyStr1 -> MyStr2 -> MyStr4

let myFun : MyStr3 = 
    fun (MyStr1 str1) (MyStr2 str2) -> MyStr4 (str1 + str2)
```

Comment: thanks! So MyStr1 is function input argument type and MyStr2 is output type. But what if I have something like: `type MyStr3 = MyStr1 -> MyStr2 -> MyStr4` What would the function look like?

Comment: @Nick added answer to your comment